# Getting 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' in my test

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright, node-worker-threads

I've written a small program using Playwright and I'm trying to make it use worker_threads. Now I've written a test for it but for some reason I'm getting the above error in my test.

I tried tweaking the tsconfig settings, but that also didn't work. What I read most about is using commonjs as the module, which I'm doing. I also installed ts-node, but that also didn't do anything.

Below is the function I wrote to create a worker.

```
import { Worker } from "worker_threads";

const create_worker = (file: string, tasksData: {}) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker(file, {
      workerData: tasksData,
    });

    worker.on("message", (data) => {
      resolve(data);
    });
    worker.on("error", (msg) => {
      reject(`An error occurred: ${msg}`);
    });
  });

export default create_worker;
```

And below is my test.

```
const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  const search_grid = await construct_search_grid();

  const chunks = chunkify_array(search_grid, 4);

  const workerPromises: unknown[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const worker = await create_worker(
      "./src/adapters/playwright.ts",
      {
        search_grid: chunks![i],
      }
    );
    workerPromises.push(worker);
  }

  const thread_results = await Promise.all(workerPromises);
```

Now I believe everything checks out so I'm not really sure what to look for now. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you don't have [tsconfig.json "module"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) configured?

I have mine set to "commonjs".  Without it, I also get that same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this error by following this guide: https://wanago.io/2019/05/06/node-js-typescript-12-worker-threads/